# The remote branch can be empty ( '' ) in sourcetree or is a bug?

Tags: git

I have recently started an android application and I want to upload to github what I have worked so far, I decided to use sourcetree for this, I created a repository with the origin name , but  when I want to push and select local branch, remote branch remains empty, does not automatically fill in the word master, like in first photo [photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUM6Q.png)

if I write the word master sometimes it shows me error as it would be empty remote branch as in picture 2 [photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rX62.png) , but sometimes it works but it cannot push me because ssh key but that would not be good and I have to restart Peagent and it appears to me as in picture 3 
[photo 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpgP8.png)

I read on the net that it would be a bug, but I didn't understand it very well, if anyone can help me, should I introduce a path or something or what should I do?

Comment: Given that your question is (apparently) about [Atlassian's SourceTree client](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), shouldn't this be tagged [sourcetree] and/or [atlassian-sourcetree] rather than [git]?